# Enable no timeout for one specific page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, asp.net-2.0, request-timed-out

I have a page that doing something, it can take 1,2 hours or even more...
After a while I get request timed out, I want that this specific page will NOT get request timed out - ever(or at least 24 hours).

How do I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Use a thread, and not a page...

Comment: I want that the person that run it will know it ended/ still running.. Can I catch that thread on other session and see its status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a thread with a signal in it to know it its still running or not. 
I suggest to use a mutex signal because is the only one that can be the same across many pools and threads.

The thread code can be:

```
public class RunThreadProcess
{
    // Some parametres
    public int cProductID;

    // my thread
    private Thread t = null;

    // start it
    public Thread Start()
    {
        t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.work));
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
        t.Start();

        return t;
    }

    // actually work
    private void work()
    {
        // while the mutex is locked, the thread is still working
        Mutex mut = new Mutex("WorkA");
        try
        {
            mut.WaitOne();

            // do thread work
            all parametres are available here

        }
        finally
        {
          mut.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
}
```

And you call it as

```
 Mutex mut = new Mutex("WorkA");

 try
 {
 if(mut.WaitOne(1000))
 {
   // release it here to start it from the thread as signal
   mut.ReleaseMutex();
   // you start the thread
   var OneAction = new RunThreadProcess();

    OneAction.cProductID = 100;
    OneAction.Start();
  }
  else
  {
     // still running
  }
 }
 finally
 {
   mut.ReleaseMutex();
 }
```

Comment: I though on your suggestion, what I though is to have a list of all threads and just print them in some page(state, alive etc..) This way I dont have to use mutex in the code.. What do you say about it?

Comment: @nir why you do won to avoid mutex ? If you go with threads, you need mutex, or else you can not control them across different pools.

Comment: What I though and implemented is to create class with static list<Thread>, and every time that I create a thread I add it to this list. And on different page just print this list for status.. This way there is not any waits on the system.. What do you think?

Comment: @nir The static is one instance per pool. If you have one pool this can work, if you assign more than a pool, the static is more than ones.